# How to create trigger to store all DML in oracle?

Tags: oracle, database-trigger

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_dml_info
 -- BEFORE LOGOFF  ON DATABASE
AFTER SELECT OR INSERT  OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON SCHEMA
   DECLARE
          session_id VARCHAR2(10),
          user_logon_name VARCHAR2(30),
          sql_idd VARCHAR2(10),
          sql_child_numbert VARCHAR2(30),
          optimizer_modee VARCHAR2(30),
          sql_textt VARCHAR2(1000)
BEGIN
SELECT x.sid  
    INTO session_id
    FROM v$sqlarea x;

SELECT x.USERNAME  
    INTO user_logon_name
    FROM v$sqlarea x;

SELECT x.SQL_ID  
    INTO sql_idd
    FROM v$sqlarea x;

SELECT x.SQL_CHILD_NUMBER  
    INTO sql_child_numbert
    FROM v$sqlarea x;

SELECT x.OPTIMIZER_MODE  
    INTO optimizer_modee
    FROM v$sqlarea x;

SELECT x.SQL_TEXT  
    INTO sql_textt
    FROM v$sqlarea x;

INSERT INTO DML$info VALUES
    (session_id,user_logon_name,sql_idd,sql_child_numbert,optimizer_modee,sql_textt)
    where x.sql_hash_value = sqlarea.hash_value
            and x.sql_address = sqlarea.address;
commit;
END;
```

Comment: Use of Oracle's auditing features would be simpler and more effective. Is there a reason you're not using that? What version of Oracle are you running?

Comment: Version: Oracle 11g and 12c

Comment: I want to have a trigger to store all DML in table when it's fired by users. therefore want to create a trigger to be fired automatically on running DML statement

Comment: Are you getting a specific error with this trigger execution?

Comment: no error, but DML Query are not stored in table

Comment: SELECT sqlarea.sql_text into sql_query
  from v$sqlarea sqlarea, v$session sesion
 where sesion.sql_hash_value = sqlarea.hash_value
   and sesion.sql_address    = sqlarea.address
   and sesion.username is not null;

Comment: above posted query i want to run within trigger and store the result into variable as already mentioned ... but does't store the result ? any help

Comment: The v$ views are volatile (content changes a lot, and quickly) and there are a number of performance issues with accessing them in this manner. From what I can tell, people have tried and failed to create the kind of trigger you're talking about since Oracle 9i. Several types of DML and recursive SQL commands do not show up in a way that the trigger can see them as they are happening, and querying the v$ views from the trigger can cause performance issues.

Comment: can we go with this scripts as test to see the performance as well ... and to store SQL statements once fired trigger into table and retrieve back by queering table .. if you can help to fix this script ... it will be your highly appreciated

Comment: The script will not work. You need to use Oracle's built-in auditing and performance monitoring features.

Comment: could you please share scripts to store DML statements?

Comment: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=log-dml-ddl-and-dcl-user-activity